# Why does lsof exceed kern.maxfiles?

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave

Running Mojave 10.14.3 I notice there are currently more files open than the maxfiles allowed.  How is this possible?  In this case I do not have any symptoms or error messages, but in the past I have seen an error message about too many open files, and that time when I checked, lsof was exactly 10000.

Side node: Is there any harm in increasing maxfiles?

```
$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 10000
$ lsof | wc
   13242  124035 1982117
```

Answer (score 3):

`lsof` lists more than just file handles. Most notably, it includes program text mapped into all processes (e.g, the executable and all libraries it's using). There are a lot of these mappings in most GUI processes -- I count over 270 for the Finder, for instance -- and they don't consume file handles.

If you believe you are hitting the *system's* open file limit, go ahead and change `kern.maxfile`. However, it's more likely that you're hitting the *per-process* open file limit, which defaults to a lower number (7168 on my system) and can be changed using `ulimit`.